# Injecting external javascript into an image

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, I want to inject an external javascript into an image, here is an example

I have 2 pages:

1. http://example.com
   This page contain this: `<img class="img" src="http://example.com/javascript/script.js">`
2. http://example.com/javascript/script.js
   And this contain this:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   var example=document.getElementsByClassName('img')[0];
>   example.style.display="none"
> </script>
> ```

Note that this just an example, i know that what i am doing is useless. Can someone please help.
Best regards!

Comment: `img` tag is for images. And `.js` files should not contain `<script>` tags. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to make this work :

```
<img class="img" src="http://example.com/javascript/script.js">
```

It wont.

Most recent browsers will not allow the use of a JavaScript in the src attribute of an image.

This technique was used to launch XSS attacks and it's now blocked by most browsers.

Comment: And if i want use it for example in a iframe?